# Calling imported functions via HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Im importing a function normally that works ok if i call it from my js file, but when i call it from the HTML with a onclick event says its not defined... im not understand that...
I import the function normally:

```
import {deleteClient} from './API.js';
```

and i call it from HTML like that:

```
<a href='#' onclick='deleteClient(31)'>delete</a>
```

Console says its not defined...However i can use it if im calling it in the js file
How i should do it? Why this happens?

Comment: There could be many reasons. Is `deleteClient` in the browser or in node? If it's in the browser, how is the JS included in the HTML?

Comment: is just linked with <script> but it seems that what i am doing is not the best way...thx anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the `onclick` attribute at all.

This is a legacy technique, which works with string evaluation (same as `eval()`). It only works when the functions are declared in the global space which is precisely what ECMAScript modules don't do (when you `import` something it is made available to the importing module only)

Use [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.